# Send list to server without json_encode dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Iam using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to communicate with the server.
How to send an list to php file in the server without json_encode in Dart with Flutter.

```
dynamic result = null;

List ids = [12, 65, 7];

Map data = {
      'name': 'Mark',  
      'ids': ids, 
};

var client = new http.Client();

  await client.post('https://example.com/control/',
headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
              },
            body: data,) 
              .then((response) => result = jsonDecode(response.body));
```

My code above dont work, The problem is I need to write `json_encode(ids)` to send the data, and when I want to get the array/list in my php file I need to write `json_decode($this->input->post('ids'))`

How to solve it without json_encode and json_encode, how to send an json object which can accept arrays without any problem?

Comment: hi, interesting, if you would prefer not to use json, you can loop over the ids and add them to your data as `data['ids[0]'] = ids[0]`. PHP will treat subscripted form items as elements of a list.

Comment: Hi, your example will be data[12] = 12, but how PHP will know that 12 is referred to ids? can you show how to fix ids list in my case?

Comment: hi, the map would look like: `{'name': 'Mark', 'ids[0]': 0, 'ids[1]: 1, ...}` - the brackets is a convention that lets PHP know that 'ids' should be an array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand completely what is the problem with sending json but you may convert your list to string like:

```dart
final idsSerialized = ids.map((id) => '$id').join(',');
```

Then send this string as payload of POST request to php script which can read value via _POST array (or your favorite way) and restore this serialized string to array:

```php
$ids = explode($_POST['ids'], ',');
```